# What's a good file format for presidencies of countries?

Tags: government, data-format

I want to build a file with all the data of the different presidents of a country. Is there a defined JSON format to represent this data?

For example:

```
{
    name: "President A",
    Assumed: '01-01-2014',
    ...
}
```

Comment: One president per country? Or do you want previous presidents too? What info do you NEED to store about each president? (for instance I see "Assumed" in your example)

Comment: Another important question: What do you actually intend to do with the data? Will it be used by an application? Do you want to share it?

Comment: Are you looking for an [Ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29)?

Comment: I want to store all the presidents of a country, the data that I want to store is the Wikipedia data that appear in the right column.

Comment: @philshem I am looking for a ontology, do you know someone to recommend?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I want to store all the data of all the president of a country.

Comment: @McSas - Ontologies aren't my thing. Please edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for, and then you are more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: @McSas I'd be glad to help, but you still haven't answered the questions in my other comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The following has the data you want, but in an HTML table format. You will need to parse it out of the tables.

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2077.html

Comment: I think that McSas is asking about how to write/organize the data in a file. This is not a data-request, I suspect McSas already has the data, probably from the source you mention or from Wikipedia.